# Python Thread Pool - process never ends

Tags: python, multithreading, process

Below is the test code - I'm playing around with the Thread Pool found in the standard library. The problem is that the final process never ends. It just hangs.

I should mention what I'm after here, func depending on input can take a few seconds to a few minutes and I want them to finish as soon as possible - in order of whatever finishes first. Ideally the number of "func" I will execute will be around four of five at the same time.

```
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
>>>
>>> def func(i):
...     import time
...     if i % 2 == 0: time.sleep(5)
...     print i
... 
>>> t = ThreadPool(5)
>>> 
>>> for i in range(10):
...     z = t.Process(target=func, args=(i,))
...     z.start()
... 
1
3
5
7
9

>>> 0
2
4
6
8
```

In other words, after printing "8" the code just waits here until I force a KeyboardInterrupt. I've tried setting the process as a daemon but no luck. Any advice/better documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue.

You should probably use for task like this

```
t.imap(func,xrange(10))
t.close()
t.join()
```